# How to get model bounding box

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using gazebo for robotic experiments in combination with ROS.

My problem is the following: given the name of a certain model in the scene (published on a topic) I need to write a ROS node that is capable of determining the bounding box of the model.

I'm searching among the various services that gazebo exposes to ROS and I came across [this](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/gazebo_msgs/html/srv/GetModelProperties.html). But I don't know how to extract the required information from this message.

Please, can someone tell me how this can be done?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17136/how-to-get-model-bounding-box/) by [federico.nardi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3295/federico.nardi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Not sure if this can be easily done through ROS without a Gazebo plugin.

With a Gazebo plugin, you could write a [model plugin](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin) and use the [physics::Model::BoundingBox()](http://gazebosim.org/api/8.0.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Model.html#a142d84ded73e7ecef9173a8d49b23e84) function.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1